# OpenErp Server Error after apps update

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I just wanted to update my apps on my OpenERP server. After this, when I log on my server, I get this error.

```
penERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 864, in authenticate
    req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 118, in authenticate
    if uid: self.get_context()
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 170, in get_context
    self.context = self.model('res.users').context_get() or {}
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 363, in context_get
    res = getattr(user,k) or False
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 497, in __getattr__
    return self[name]
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 405, in __getitem__
    field_values = self._table.read(self._cr, self._uid, ids, field_names, context=self._context, load="_classic_write")
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 810, in read
    res = super(users_view, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields, context=context, load=load)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py", line 272, in read
    result = super(res_users, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3625, in read
    result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3702, in _read_flat
    res2 = self.pool.get(table).read(cr, user, [x[col] for x in res], cols, context, load)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3625, in read
    result = self._read_flat(cr, user, select, fields, context, load)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3677, in _read_flat
    cr.execute(query, [tuple(sub_ids)] + rule_params)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: column res_partner.supplier_direct_debit does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT res_partner."ean13",res_partner."supplier_direct_debi...                                 ^
```

However, I still connect to my server with FTP and ssh but I'm new and I have no idea how to solve this error.

**Edit :** I didn't found the solution so I used a backup, anyway thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`ProgrammingError: column res_partner.supplier_direct_debit does not exist` means that `supplier_direct_debit` field does not exist in `res.partner` model.
If you do not need that field remove it from view definition( in xml file),
if not add it to `res.pârtner`:

```
class res_patner(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    _columns = {
    'supplier_direct_debit': fields.float(),
    }
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but I've no idea where is this XML file pls.

Comment: @hemir May be you forgot to upgrade a module.

Answer (score 0):

restart your server with command 
./openerp-server -c openerp-server.conf -d your_database_name -u all

this will update your all modules.